# Proxies in the get method of requests module dont seem to work

Tags: python, python-requests, proxies

I've googled the syntax for proxies and it should be the same as in my code and there is no other way around but anyways, after using proxies, https://api.ipify.org still returns my own external ip address.

```
import requests
import random


def get_site():
    http = ['85.26.146.169:80', '85.143.70.165:80', '213.135.118.150:3128']
    proxi = {
        'http': 'http://'+random.choice(http)
    }
    # proxi = {
    #     'http': 'http://85.26.146.169:80'
    # }
    print(requests.get('https://api.ipify.org', proxies=proxi).text)

get_site()
```

both commented and uncommented variants dont work

P.S. after changing protocol from http to https now it is working but I doubt that every single one from 18 proxies doesnt work and also i can easily ping them. they're free though

```
import requests
import random


def get_site():
    https = ['188.134.65.80:41890', '77.236.243.69:1256', '31.163.192.161:3129', '37.110.6.178:8080',
             '31.131.67.14:8080', '77.238.129.14:55443', '85.235.184.186:3129', '195.133.71.199:8080',
             '95.189.104.181:41890',
             '78.36.198.158:80',
             '188.246.186.142:41890',
             '95.140.31.39:41890',
             '178.74.103.46:8080',
             '212.46.255.78:8080',
             '195.68.187.222:3128',
             '81.24.95.176:41258',
             '89.22.152.32:53726',
             '84.201.254.47:3128']
    for i in range(len(https)):
        proxi = {
            'https': 'https://' + https[i]
        }
        print(requests.get('https://api.ipify.org', proxies=proxi).text)
```

Comment: Your proxy specification is only relevant for HTTP. Your URL is using the HTTPS scheme

Comment: thanks) maybe its irrelevant already but now if I try a bunch of proxies with https nothing not a single one proxy is working and there is no return with an ip, only errors sometimes. is it because all of them aren't available? (I will add the code example)

Comment: It's possible that the proxies that support HTTPS require authentication. None of them work (within a 2 second timeout) for me. Only a few of your proxies work for HTTP

Comment: they are free so there is no authentication but it's really strange that I can't find at least one that works. thanks anyway again)